# How to change the lock screen background on Windows 8.1 to a custom folder?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, lock-screen

I have a bunch of wallpapers synced in Google Drive, and a seperate folder I use as the "Pictures"-folder. When I'm trying to add a custom folder (my wallpaper folder in Google Drive), I simply don't get the option.
I can browse for different folders, but I can't see anything outside the ordinary Pictures folder. If I click "This PC" or go up a level, I simply see nothing and can't find my custom folders.

I know I could move my wallpaper folder from Google Drive to SkyDrive, but I'm trying to avoid that because I want to use SkyDrive for other uses without having to pay for more space.

How do I pick a folder outside the Pictures folder?